# how can i also search my id, middlename,lastname in my search textbox

Tags: c#, database, forms

How can I also search my id, middlename, lastname in my search text box? I cant use WHERE CONCAT() because my database is just a built-in in microsoft visual studio 2010

```
    private void textBox14_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                       
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox14.Text))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from table1", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        }
        else
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Gender, DateofBirth, PlaceofBirth, Address, FathersName, FathersOccupation, MothersName, MothersOccupation, Guardian, Relation, GuardianOccupation, image FROM table1 WHERE FirstName LIKE'" + textBox14.Text + "%'", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is the t-SQL language nonetheless. you can use the + operator to concatenate strings. two issues with that: 1) poor performance 2) your approach is not [safe for scripting](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp), use parameters. If you need to search for composites, it is often better to add a column to the table where the pre-computed text is stored. this adds redundancy and size to the database, but in times where storage is cheap...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OR to the multiple things you want to search from the textbox. Try this:

```
private void textBox14_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox14.Text))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from table1", con);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(data);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }

    else
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Gender, DateofBirth, PlaceofBirth, Address, FathersName, FathersOccupation, MothersName, MothersOccupation, Guardian, Relation, GuardianOccupation, image FROM table1 WHERE FirstName LIKE'" + textBox14.Text + "%' OR id LIKE'" + textBox14.Text + "%' OR MiddleName LIKE'" + textBox14.Text + "%' OR LastName LIKE'" + textBox14.Text + "%'", con);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(data);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }



}
```

Comment: this is four times less safe for scripting than the original :)

Comment: Why it is not safe?

Comment: users could engineer their input and inject malicious code, because the input is taken directly from textboxes. http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: But for that you ought to implement sql injection prevention. Her question was answered based on her doubt and there is nothing deprecated about the code.

Comment: absolutely. until the next guy comes along and criticizes this post for not using `using` with `SqlDataAdapter` which is `IDisposable`. oops, I just did :)
no seriously, SQL injection is such a basic yet commonplace vulnerability, and we should contribute to its eradication whenever possible.